# How to execute a command for all mp3 files in a directory?

Tags: shell, files

I have a directory with some mp3 files. I want to remove (almost) all ID3 tags using

```
mid3v2 <file> --delete-frames=AENC,APIC,...
```

for every mp3 file in the directory. Other files should not be modified. How do I do this?

Edit:

```
find /directory_with_mp3_files -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mid3v2 {} --delete-frames=AENC,APIC,...
```

got the job done.

Comment: I would also look at this: https://picard.musicbrainz.org
It's a great piece of software for achieving sane ID3 tags even though it's not exactly what you asked.

Comment: you should write an answer rather than edit your question. after a while it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /directory_with_mp3_files -name '*.mp3' |xargs -I {} mid3v2 {} --delete-frames=AENC,APIC,...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error:
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: Spaces and/or funny chars (apostrophee, ampersands etc. are usual for track i.e. file names) is the most probable re reason. 
try replacing `-name '*.mp3' |xargs `  part with  `-name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0`